# How to set a HTTPS communication with a AWS Balancer and X Servers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, load-balancing

I have a webapp installed in X windows servers, in front of that servers i have an AWS Balancer, before settings the balancer i had only one server with SSL cert on the webapp.

Should the SSL be only on the balancer or should i generate SSL cert for each server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do either. The load balancer can terminate TLS and rely on AWS network isolation to keep unencrypted communications secure, or you can use https to each server.

http within AWS is fairly secure since AWS keeps traffic isolated. However, to be sure, you might want to encrypt your traffic between the load balancer and your instances. If you have particular compliance requirements like PCI or CIS you may have to encrypt traffic to the servers.